# HTML/PHP Form - Input Type "Date"

Tags: php

i am struggling to pull through a "Date" input type on my php form processor to email.
I've tried various coding but cannot get the value to show on email :-(

everything else works - assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$reference = $_POST['reference'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$email_from = 'my email here';
$email_subject = "Online Payment Notification";
$email_body = "You have received an online payment notification from $name.\n".
"please see details below:\n

Name: $name
Email: $visitor_email
Reference#: $reference
Date: $date
Amount: £$amount
";

$to = "my email here";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: So what do you actually get?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML form too ? that'd help

Comment: what shows in place of the date?

Comment: do you get anything?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your PHP code as far as I can see. Note that the value in `$_POST` is the NAME of the input, not the type. If you have something along the lines of `<input type="date" name="date" />` you should be good.

Comment: it seems to be working now, must be a server lag or something however the date is showing as YYYY-MM-DD but i want it to show as DD-MM-YYYY - any ideas?

Comment: @Steve Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [The] Date is showing as YYYY-MM-DD but i want it to show as
>   DD-MM-YYYY

To change the format of the date from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY, simply replace this line of code:

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
```

with:

```
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Comment: i've tried this but the below error keep coming back.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'd' (T_STRING)

Comment: @Steve Do you only see the error after using my code, or before you add it?

Comment: only when i add it - without your code it displays in the email as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @Steve Okay. Please remove my code and simply put `echo $_POST['date']` - what does it display?

Comment: you mean like this?

Name: $name
Email: $visitor_email
Reference#: $reference
Date: $date echo $_POST['date']
Amount: £$amount

Comment: @Steve I think you may be putting my code in the wrong place. Please replace `$date = $_POST['date'];` with `$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['date']));`

Comment: i was putting it in the wrong place ! sorry !
thank you !

Comment: @Steve That's no problem :)

Comment: @Steve Please accept my answer if it solved the problem